# Is there a way to quickly disable all root certificates in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I'd like to temporarily disable all trusted root certificates and wondering if there is a quicker way than going through every single one of them, right-click Properties and selecting "Disable all purposes for this certificate" (and then trying to find where I left off after the list in mmc scrolls back to the top)?

Comment: I'm going to guess there's a way to script it, since in an enterprise the sysadmins would not want to visit every desktop.  Try serverfault, might have more luck there.